# How to downgrade mlflow without data loss

Tags: mlflow

What would be a correct way of downgrading mlflow say from 2.9 to 1.30 without loosing data? The problem is the sql schema that is not compatible between versions.

I did manage to solve the problem by having 2 backends and a python script that sends experiments from one to the other, but I feel this is a hack/brute force at best